# Clojure db-do-prepared calling with multiple parameters

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I see following example in `Clojure.java.jdbc`

```
(sql/db-do-prepared db "INSERT INTO fruit2 ( name, appearance, cost, grade ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" ["test" "test" 1 1.0])
```

But how do i convert following  `java` code into `clojure`. I am new to `clojure` and not sure how to i pass multiple `vector`

```
final int numRows = 10000;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
        .prepareStatement("insert into new_order values (?, ?, ?)");
    for (int id = 1; id <= numRows; id++) {
      pstmt.setInt(1, id % 98);
      pstmt.setInt(2, id % 98);
      pstmt.setInt(3, id);
      int count;
      if ((count = pstmt.executeUpdate()) != 1) {
        System.err.println("unexpected update count for a single insert " + count);
        System.exit(2);
      }
      if ((id % 500) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Completed " + id + " inserts ...");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following your question. Would you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for multiple vectors, the function is varargs:

```
(sql/db-do-prepared db "INSERT INTO fruit2 ( name, appearance, cost, grade ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" ["test" "test" 1 1.0] ["test" "test" 2 3.0])
```

If you want to generate the input from a list, you can use apply:

```
(apply sql/db-do-prepared db "INSERT INTO fruit2 ( name, appearance, cost, grade ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" (for [i (range 10)] ["test" "test" i 1.0]))
```

For a literal reproduction of that logic, you cannot use the varargs, because it does not give you a chance to check each return value before the next operation:

```
(let [num-rows 1000
      success
      (reduce
       (fn [state id]
         (let [values [(mod id 98)
                       (mod id 98)
                       id]
               [result] (sql/do-prepared "insert into test values (?)" values)]
           (if (not= result 1)
             {:ok id}
             (reduced {:error result}))))
       (range 1 (inc num-rows)))]
  (if-let [id (:ok success)]
    (println "Completed" id "inserts")
    (do (println "unexpected update count for a single insert" (:error success))
        (System/exit 2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I think @noisesmith is right except I think the `sql-params` should be in collection (vector).

(sql/db-do-prepared 
  db
  ["INSERT INTO fruit2 ( name, appearance, cost, grade ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )" 
   "test" "test" 1 1.0])

I think this works for me (am I missing something please let me know)

Or maybe the API changed since 2013